# Using Facebook Social Plugins: fb-share-button

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, firewall

Facebook provides a couple of [Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) that users can embed into their web sites.

1. **Is it possible to customize these plugins**, e.g. change the text and image of the `fb-share-button`?
2. Furthermore, I experienced problems when loading the below sample page at my office. I suppose, our enterprise firewall blocks Facebook, so the page loads really slow and the share button is not shown. I do understand that the button cannot be shown, if content is blocked by the network, but **are there any means I can prevent the rest of the page from loading so slow**, if my page visitors are on a restricted network? Like, does it make sense to move the `script` block to the very end of the page or...?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>fb-share-button Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor est</div>

        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="icon"></div>
            
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Customization of the social plugins is very limited. (If you want a custom link/button to trigger a share, then you can to use the Share _dialog_ instead) 2. That code loads the script asynchronously already, so moving it somewhere else should not increase performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll need to sign up for a Facebook app, if I want to use a Share dialog, right? The Social Plugins do not require any registration.

Comment: Using the `FB.ui` method of calling the dialog should work with the JS SDK as you have already embedded it.